# How can I use handcrafted features along with a Pretrained model for image classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification

I want to use a handcrafted feature like HOG etc and combine it with a Pretrained model like VGG and study the accuracy

I just dont know how to combine both the things together